# Am I abusing git by making my home directory a repo and then having other repos within it?

Tags: git

For years, I've set up my home directory as a git repo:

```
~ $ ls -a
.git/  .vim/  code/  .bash_history  .bashrc  .gitconfig  .gitignore  .vimrc
```

I'm careful not to commit files that contain sensitive information (e.g. my private ssh key). In fact, I ignore everything except a few files:

```
~ $ cat .gitignore
# ignore everything
*

# except these
!.bashrc
!.gitignore
!.vimrc
```

Normally, I have several projects in `code/` with their own git repos:

```
~ $ ls -a code/
ctest/  cpptest/  dwm/

~ $ ls -a code/ctest/
.git/  pointers  pointers.c  strings  strings.c
```

It never occurred to me that this was strange until a coworker raised concerns about it. Am I somehow abusing git by setting up my home directory this way? Can it lead to problems with programs attempting to use my dot files?

Comment: What are you accomplishing by this?  Do you want to keep a history of all of the files that have ever graced your /home directory, or are you keeping a backup of them instead?

Comment: I want to a) track my dot files and b) be able to clone them on another machine.

Comment: So what you want are backups as opposed to a Git repository.  The only time I've ever used Git on a config file was if I knew the file was subject to lots of small and easy-to-forget changes, since the files that you're not ignoring aren't subject to lots of change over a huge period of time.  If you're genuinely worried, you *could* create a single folder as the Git repository to all of those files, then symlink the configuration files across to where you need it.

Comment: Your public SSH key is not sensitive information. The private one is. Hence the names "public" and "private".

Comment: you can make a dotfiles directory in your `/home/` and make symlinks between `.bashrc` and `~/dotfiles/bashrc`. It would be proper and allow easy management (both for deployment and privacy concerns as you can push it on github)

Comment: IMO this is very much overkill. Managing dotfiles in git is not difficult and is simpler to do with a repo plus symlinks managed by an install script. Here is how I do mine: https://github.com/tangledhelix/dotfiles (see install.pl for how it is managed)

Comment: @MadPhysicist that's what I meant :)

Comment: @Makoto No, you definitely want a repository and not backups, because you might want the history on your files so you can also revert changes etc. Backups are a quite naive last resort kind of thing and you hope never having to use a backup. Dotfiles you may want to use on multiple machines etc. And just copying files away every now and then is so 90s.

Comment: @IngoBürk:  Not that I disagree (I even mentioned that I did something similar in those situations), but making your ***entire*** home directory a Git repository is not ideal.

Comment: Mods, instead of closing the question because it's opinion based, can it be moved to programmers SE or something?

Comment: Making the entire home directory a Git repository can be dangerous, because a git command invoked in a wrong directory may then act on the whole home directory. E.g., `git -fdx` will remove everything except nested non-bare Git repositories.

Answer (score 11):

It's definitely *not* crazy to put your dotfiles in git.  I do it so that I can easily sync my configuration among multiple machines and [I'm not alone](https://dotfiles.github.io).

That said, it *is* poor form to have a git repository in your home directory and then have other repos beneath it.

Some people solve this by checking out their dotfiles repo into a sub directory of `$HOME` and then symlinking those files into home.  (There are some scripts to help manage this at https://dotfiles.github.io.

Personally, I don't like symlinking and instead create my dotfiles repo in a directory that is not `.git` (for example: `.dotfiles.git`).  You can simply rename the `.git` folder to `.dotfiles.git`.  Then you can:

```
git checkout --git-dir=.dotfiles.git checkout .profile
```

Comment: Just my 2¢: with this `--git-dir` trick it's possible to use *entire* filesystem as a Git repository and save system-wide configuration, too. This is how I did it on my machine: `alias gith="git --git-dir='/home/me/…/dotfiles.git' --work-tree=/"`.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think that your idea is fundamentally abusive of the concept of Git. Git is effectively a versioning file system. From the [Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals):

> First, if it isn’t yet clear, Git is fundamentally a content-addressable filesystem with a VCS user interface written on top of it.

In fact, this has been made official with projects like [`gitfs`](https://www.presslabs.com/gitfs/), which allows you to mount a git repo instead of cloning it.

I am not sure what problems you are expecting with dotfiles. Git handles them just like any other file type. Same goes for your coworker's concerns. Unless there is something specific, they are probably unfounded. All git really does is add a .git folder to your home directory. Unless you are running git commands, having this folder does nothing to your other files. Git does not normally clobber things unless you very specifically tell it to, so that should not be a major concern either.

To sum up, your idea is not wild. It is harnessing the intention of Git's design, and should not cause any problems in and of itself.

Answer (score 2):

- I don't think that you abuse git, it was built for heavy usage.
- I don't think that your any program will have an issue accessing your dotfiles. Though, you should be careful in cases where you want to revert the state of your home directory, because you might lose changes, or you might corrupt the contents of the files and this is the first concern I would raise regarding this usage. The second concern is disk space, which can grow a lot if you don't take care of it or if you store a lot of binary data.